# Disable parentheses auto-completion in TeXStudio 2.7.0

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

Previously, it was possible to disable parentheses auto-completion in TeXStudio through the advanced options in the Configure options.  Is this still possible in version 2.7.0?  Here's a screen shot of my configuration window for completion and the parentheses option is no longer there:

[image: TeXstudio configure screenshot]

Any tips on disabling parentheses (including braces and brackets) in 2.7.0?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the "Completion" Configuration panel, which refers to auto-completion of Latex commands. The option to (un)check "Auto Complete Parentheses" is in the "Adv Editor" pane.